# Probability of Finding A Lower Minimum

Tags: statistics, optimization

I have a system *f($\vec x$)* periodically bounded by *{$\vec a$}* and I would prefer to find the absolute minimum. Suppose I drop *n* balls that always roll to the bottom of a local minimum, and from them, I gather data of *f($\vec x$)* along with the paths *$\vec x$(t)* they have taken. I take the lowest value of these minima, *M$_i$*, which is my proposed absolute minimum. How do I quantify the probability that I will find a comparable or lower minimum if I were to drop more balls into the system (e.g. $M_{i+1}< M_i+0.1|M_i|)$?